# How can i combine 2 text files but not overwriting whats on the 1st file?

Tags: javascript, python, php, html

For example on one file i have

a=red

b=blue

c=green

on second file i have

a=yellow

b=pink

c=purple

d=black

e=white

how can i easily transfer d and e to first file without manually searching and copy pasting d and e and without it altering what ABC is on first file? ?

(in real world scenario there'd be hundred of items not just 5 like this example)

i was trying to use notepad++ with some kind of advance merge or find and replace but that didn't seem to work. I asked around and people suggested that its a programming problem, not simple word processing problem

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Also are file 1 and file 2 in a sorted order? I.E I only have to append data to the end of file 1 when i find a line in file 2 thats not in file 1?

Comment: open file1 using `fopen()` with `append mode`. Now open second file usign `fopen()` in read mode. read content for second file and add that to first

Comment: @ChrisDoyle unfortunately theyre not in sorted order. sometimes the new items on second file is listed in the middle but they can be placed anywhere in first file

Comment: Does the characters before the '='  (such as a, b, c) act as a unique identifier for items in the two files? So would you only need to add items when it's identifier is in file2 but not in file1?

Comment: @DarrylG yes abc is unique. yup only add items found in file 2 thats not already in file 1

Comment: In that case, @Błotosmętek answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

A Python solution, assuming your files are named `1.txt` and `2.txt`:

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:
   d1 = dict( line.rstrip().split('=') for line in f )
with open('2.txt', 'r') as f:
   d2 = dict( line.rstrip().split('=') for line in f )
for k in d2:
    if k not in d1:
        d1[k] = d2[k]
with open('1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for t in d1.items():
        f.write('{}={}\n'.format(t))
```